# Covert Text file data to Datatable

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, datatable

My text file contains such data. I want to read this data from text file and convert it into datatable.

```
FacilityID:   12787
FacilityName: ACME Medical Center
Facility Location: 
RecordID:            16611730-19049181-20529397-14136226
Patient:           Kistra Halos
Gender:            Female
DOB:               7/20/1955
```

while reading this input its not showing me output in datatable like this

```
FacilityID:   12787
FacilityName: ACME Medical Center
Facility Location: 
RecordID:            16611730-19049181-20529397-14136226
Patient:           Kistra Halos
Gender:            Female
DOB:               7/20/1955
```

but I want it as:

```
FacilityID  FacilityName  Facility Location  RecordID  Patient  Gender  DOB
12787       ACME Medical                    16611730-. Kistra   Female 7/20/1955
```

var table = new DataTable();

```
    var fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\simple.txt");

    var splitFileContents = (from f in fileContents select f.Split(':')).ToArray();

    int maxLength = (from s in splitFileContents select s.Count()).Max();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add();
    }


    foreach (var line in splitFileContents)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row.ItemArray = (object[])line;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

I want to perform the search, sort operations on it. So How I can convert it.

Comment: Why don't just read the file line by line and write the information into your DataTable? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Yes I have tried this I update the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can look for the first occurrence of the colon in each line. The part before is the column-name and the part behind is the value.

Try this approach:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
var lines = File.ReadLines(pathToFile).Where(l => l.Contains(':'));
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    int index = line.IndexOf(':');
    string column = line.Trim().Remove(index);
    string value = line.Trim().Substring(index + 1).Trim();
    DataColumn col = table.Columns[column];
    if (col == null)
        col = table.Columns.Add(column);
    bool isNewRecord = col.Ordinal == 0;
    DataRow row = isNewRecord ? table.Rows.Add() : table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1];
    row.SetField(column, value);
}
```

You can then use `Linq-To-DataTable` to sort the table or to find specific rows.

For example:

```
var rows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("FacilityID") == "12787");
DataRow firstRow = rows.FirstOrDefault();
if(firstRow != null)
{
     // for example:
     string patient = firstRow.Field<string>("Patient"); // Kistra Halos
     // ....
}
```

Comment: Tim: answer was peretty good one!!!  Do we have some other aprroach other than Datatable means we can retrieve data from text file suing Linq or else and filter it.

Comment: Sure. But I dont know what issue you have. Maybe you should post a question. You could let me know and I'll try to answer then.